# Как правильно вводить значения для двух списков с клавиатуры?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот формат ввода:

```
n
a[0] b[0]
a[1] b[1]
...  ...
a[n] b[n]
```

Вот пример ввода:

```
3
1 100
2 200
3 300
```

Как лучше и короче всего осуществить такой ввод данных с клавиатуры, чтобы поместить целые числа из первого столбца в список "a", а целые числа из второго столбца в список "b"?

Т. е. на выходе должно получиться:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [100, 200, 300]
```

Comment: input().split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте:

- [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) для получения ввода (как строка)
- `int` для конвертации строки в целое число
- `range` для вызова указанного количества итераций
- `str.split` для разбиения строки на список по пробелам

Пример:

```
n = int(input())
items_a = []
items_b = []

for _ in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    items_a.append(a)
    items_b.append(b)

print(items_a)
print(items_b)
```

Для введенных значений:

```
3
1 100
2 200
3 300
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[100, 200, 300]
```

Comment: Нужно поместить целые числа из первого столбца в список "a", а целые числа из второго столбца в список "b"

Comment: @Борис, ок, обновил )

Comment: а нет более компактной записи на подобии этой `a = [int(input()) for i in pange(3)]` , только для двух массивов одновременно?

Comment: @Борис, `a, b = [(int(input()), int(input())) for i in pange(3)]`?

Comment: да, желательно в одну строку. Но этот способ не работает.

Comment: @Борис, можно так `items = [(int(input()), int(input())) for i in range(3)]` и `a, b = [a for a, b in items], [a for a, b in items]`, но это уже замудренность. Либо: `a, b = [], []` и `[a.append(int(input())) or b.append(int(input())) for i in range(3)]`